# Getting Unknown error in charles during inspecting api websocket of an android app

Tags: websocket, charles-proxy, sniffing, apprequests

Hey Some Days ago am working with charles nd its working properly but now i am unable to use it, it shows me unknown. I tried with 2 android (android pie) & 1 android emulator (android lollipop including root). I tried with all network security config below:

1) Given on Charles Official website

```
<network-security-config> 
  <debug-overrides> 
    <trust-anchors> 
      <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
      <certificates src="user" /> 
    </trust-anchors> 
  </debug-overrides> 
</network-security-config>
```

2) From other sources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

I was using 2nd network security config when its working properly. Is there any solution or alternative method to inspect the responses and websockets inside the app.

Comment: An alternative approach is that using other tools like Fiddler or Proxyman. https://proxyman.io/blog/2019/10/WebSocket-Debugging.html

Comment: Yeah i am using fiddler but its too much different then charles, in fiddler all all things get messed up but in charles things dont get messed up & as i am using windows i cant use proxyman btw thanks for suggestion when i will buy macos i will try it.